# Grand Theft Auto 5 not loading

Tags: ps3, grand-theft-auto-v

I bought a copy of Grand Theft Auto 5 from Lukie Games. But when i put it in my ps3 it starts loading the story mode. The problem is it wont do more than that, it just stays on that screen of the blond getting arrested, not loading. Anyone else have this problem? If so can you tell me how to fix it?

Comment: Did you buy a used copy? If so, this sounds like a scratched disc. Have you tried using the disc in a different PS3?

Comment: Have you tried installing the game to the hard drive?

Comment: Yes Studoku, I bought the game used. And now that i think about it, i did see a scratch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is almost certainly caused by a scratched disc- an unfortunate risk of buying second hand. You have two choices.

1. Get the disk returned or replaced. Since Lukie Games sent you a damaged product, you are legally entitled to a refund or replacement. I've never dealt with or even heard of Lukie Games before, but I recommend contacting them.
2. Get the disk repaired. Scratches can often be repaired by professionals. Some game or computer stores may offer this service. You will, of course, have to pay. I'd recommend trying to get the refund first.

Comment: Thank you Studoku, i have contacted lukie games and i will get a refund. Thank you!

Comment: @user69492 Glad I could help.